# C - issues with sizeof (featuring strtok)

Tags: c, string, output, size, strtok

**Edit: I later discovered this issue mainly stemmed from my confusion with** *sizeof* **, and replacing it with** *strlen* **was pretty much my solution. My answer (scroll down) presents a decent but simple example of** *strtok* **if you're interested as well.**

So I've been trying to get a program working where I input a list of words separated by commas, and it subsequently outputs those words, line by line, and removing any spaces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define delim ","

int main() {
    //variable declaration:
    char words[100];
    char *word;
    char tempWord[100];
    int n;

    //gets input assinged to "words":
    puts("\nEnter a list of words separated by commas.\n");
    fgets(words, sizeof(words), stdin);


    //sets up the first word in strtok
    word = strtok(words, delim);

    //loops so long as the word isn't null (reaching the last word)
    while (word != NULL) {
        puts("\n");

        //checks if each character in the word is a space (and ignores them if they are)
        for (n = 0; n < sizeof(word); ++n) {

            //for some reason can't directly use word (probably because it's a pointer)
            //so have to copy it to a temporary value
            strcpy(tempWord, word);

            //don't print if it's a space
            if (!isspace(tempWord[n])) printf("%c", tempWord[n]);
        }

        //moves to next word
        word = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

by inputting *"LETS, FREAKINGG, GOOOOOOOOOOOO"*, I seem to encounter an issue:

*(running the program):*

```
Enter a list of words separated by commas.

(input) >>>LETS, FREAKINGG, GOOOOOOOOOOOO


LETS

FREAKIN

GOOOOOO
```

It seems depending on the size of the first word, it sets an character limit to be no more than 3 beyond that for subsequent words. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: `word` is a pointer variable. `sizeof(word)` is therefore the size of a pointer. It is not the size of the thing being pointed at, which cannot be known at compile time (and `sizeof` is a compile-time operator). Since you seem to be running on a platform where addresses are 64 bits (8 bytes),  this loop `for (n = 0; n < sizeof(word); ++n)` iterates exactly 8 times, which is why your words seem to be cut off. For shorter words, the loop will overrun.

Comment: And to add to the previous comment - use `strlen(word)` instead of `sizeof`. Other issues: Don't need `strcpy` into another buffer and certainly not for every iteration.

Comment: `tempWord` and the `strcpy` are totally unnecessary. Even if they were useful, it seems pointless to do the copy at every character position, since `word` isn't being changed while the loop runs. But there's no reason for it at all and the comment which says there is a reason is unconvincing. Finally, C strings are terminated by a NUL character (that is, a 0). So writing loops which first figure out how long the string is and then iterate that many times are just doing double work:  there's no way to compute the length of a string other than to search for the NUL. Just loop until you hit NUL.

Comment: @kaylum thank you!! I have added an answer to my own question with the resolved code. I'm not too bothered about it lacking in efficiency, just clearing up my confusion with sizeof has helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you ***@rici*** and ***@kaylum*** for the responses!

For some reason I was getting some errors before when not copying the word to a temporary variable, I'm not entirely sure what I was thinking by putting it inside of the for-loop but it works without! Just a very small brain moment...

I believe my confusion was around **sizeof()**, and replacing with **strlen()** is a *complete fix* for this!

**Here's the amended (working) code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define delim ","

int main() {
    //variable declaration:
    char words[100];
    char *word;
    int n;

    //gets input assinged to "words":
    puts("\nEnter a list of words separated by commas.\n");
    fgets(words, sizeof(words), stdin);


    //sets up the first word in strtok
    word = strtok(words, delim);

    //loops so long as the word isn't null (reaching the last word)
    while (word != NULL) {
        puts("\n");

        //checks if each character in the word is a space (and ignores them if they are)
        for (n = 0; n < strlen(word); ++n) {

            //don't print if it's a space
            if (!isspace(word[n])) printf("%c", word[n]);
        }

        //moves to next word
        word = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

**and the output:**

```
Enter a list of words separated by commas.

(input) >>>LETS, FREAKINGG, GOOOOOOOOOOOO


LETS

FREAKINGG

GOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

Thank you very much for the help!